# MagicalRecord import without primary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

Is there a way to import data with Magical Record that does not have `primaryKey` or `relatedByAttribute`?

My JSON looks like this. As you can see this is a list of services that an employee has access too. There is no unique ID for me to relate too.

```
{
   "status":0,
   "statusMessage":"Call success",
   "details":{
      "items":[
         {
            "status":0,
            "statusMessage":"Employee service schedule list returned",
            "details":{
               "itemsReturned":2,
               "items":[
                  {
                     "clientId":747,
                     "employeeId":2241,
                     "serviceId":3137,
                     "duration":60,
                     "scheduleMondayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleMondayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleTuesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleTuesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleWednesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleWednesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleThursdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleThursdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleFridayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleFridayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleSaturdayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSaturdayEndTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayEndTime":null
                  },
                  {
                     "clientId":747,
                     "employeeId":7178,
                     "serviceId":3137,
                     "duration":60,
                     "scheduleMondayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleMondayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleTuesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleTuesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleWednesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleWednesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleThursdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleThursdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleFridayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleFridayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleSaturdayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSaturdayEndTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayEndTime":null
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "status":0,
            "statusMessage":"Employee service schedule list returned",
            "details":{
               "itemsReturned":2,
               "items":[
                  {
                     "clientId":747,
                     "employeeId":2241,
                     "serviceId":3138,
                     "duration":5,
                     "scheduleMondayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleMondayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleTuesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleTuesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleWednesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleWednesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleThursdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleThursdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleFridayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleFridayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleSaturdayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSaturdayEndTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayEndTime":null
                  },
                  {
                     "clientId":747,
                     "employeeId":7178,
                     "serviceId":3138,
                     "duration":5,
                     "scheduleMondayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleMondayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleTuesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleTuesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleWednesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleWednesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleThursdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleThursdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleFridayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleFridayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleSaturdayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSaturdayEndTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayEndTime":null
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "status":0,
            "statusMessage":"Employee service schedule list returned",
            "details":{
               "itemsReturned":1,
               "items":[
                  {
                     "clientId":747,
                     "employeeId":7178,
                     "serviceId":3139,
                     "duration":15,
                     "scheduleMondayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleMondayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleTuesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleTuesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleWednesdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleWednesdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleThursdayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleThursdayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleFridayStartTime":480,
                     "scheduleFridayEndTime":1020,
                     "scheduleSaturdayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSaturdayEndTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayStartTime":null,
                     "scheduleSundayEndTime":null
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What is the best way to import these with magical record without a unique id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MagicalRecord importing should still work with this data. Since you've got objects related via a json key, we can know what you want to relate your core data entities with. In addition, as long as you map your json properties to the core data attributes correctly, that also provides enough information for the import library to figure out what should be related to what on import.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "i have them related via a json key"?

Comment: When you define your property mapping in the Core Data model editor, you need to basically tell the MagicalRecord importing library how each core data property/attribute maps to each json attribute. Have a look at this blog post I wrote a while back for more details: http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/

Comment: Ahh yes I do use `mappedKeyName`. But if I do not have a `relatedByAttribute` or a `entityID` then it will crash.

Comment: The import functions should also use a convention based on your core data property name. If you have a property named 'department', it'll look for 'departmentID'. But other than that, you need to specify a mapping. There has to be some way to connect data to the model, this was the minimum required info I found to get things to work properly.

Comment: I think we are thinking of different things. My entity has all the properties which match the json response for each `details.items` inside of the first `details.items`. It seems unless there is a unique ID you cannot use import.

Comment: Are you saying to create one with `<entity>ID` but not map it to anything in my json? EDIT: adding a `<entity>ID` and not mapping it to a field did the trick!